# Regular Expression to DFA

Tags: regex, finite-automata, automata, dfa, automata-theory

Can someone tell me if the attached DFA is correct ?

I am suppose to give DFA for the language that has alphabet Σ ={a, b}

I need DFA for this ----> A={ε, b, ab} [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for multiple reasons:

1. Your automaton `bab`
2. Your automaton does not accept `ab`
3. Your automaton is not a DFA, at least by some strict definitions

Regarding the first point: starting at `q1`, we see `b`, go to `q2`, see `a`, go to `q3`, see `b`, and go to `q4`, which is accepting. We saw `bab` and accepted it.

Regarding the second point: starting at `q1`, we see `a` but have no defined transition. The automaton "crashes" and fails to accept. So no string starting with `a` is accepted, including `ab`.

Regarding the third point: DFAs are often required to show all states and transitions, including dead states and transitions that will never lead back to any accepting state. You don't show all transitions and don't show all states in your automaton.

You can use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to determine how many states a minimal DFA for your language has. We note that the empty state can have appended either the empty string, `b` or `ab` to get a string in the language; `a` can have `b` appended; and `b` can have the empty string appended. Nothing can be appended to `aa`, `bb`, or `ba` to get a string in the language (so these are indistinguishable); but `ab` can have the empty string appended (and so is indistinguishable from `b`).

Equivalence classes so determined correspond to states in a minimal DFA. Our equivalence classes are:

1. Strings like the empty string
2. Strings like `b`
3. Strings like `a`
4. Strings like `aa`

We note that `b` is in the language, so the second class will correspond to an accepting state. We notice nothing can be appended to `aa` to get a string in the language, so this class corresponds to a dead state in the DFA. We write the transitions between these states by seeing which new equivalence class the appending of a new symbol puts us in:

1. Appending `a` puts us in (3) since appending `a` to the empty string gives `a` which is in (3). Appending `b` puts us in (2) since appending `b` to the empty string gives `b` which is in (2)
2. Appending `a` puts us in (4) since appending `a` to to `b` gives `ba` which is like `aa` in that it isn't a prefix of any string in the language. Appending `b`, we arrive in (4) by a similar argument.
3. Appending `a` we get `aa` and are in (4). Appending `b` we get `ab` which is like `b` so we are in (2).
4. All transitions from a dead state return to a dead state; both `a` and `b` lead back to (4).

You end up with something like:

```
q1 --a--> q3
 |        /|
 b  --b--< a
 | /       |
 vv        v
q2 -a,b-> q4 \
           ^ a,b
           \_/
```

Or in tabular form:

```
q    s    q'
==   =    ==
q1   a    q3
q1   b    q2
q2   a    q4
q2   b    q4
q3   a    q4
q3   b    q2
q4   a    q4
q4   b    q4
```

Comment: Thnks for explaining in this much detail. I have better picture of DFA now.

Comment: May i know in the above DFA that you provided me q1 (that would accept ε) , q2 (would accept b) and q4 (would accept ab). So i believe to justify accepting state i should do double circle on q1, q2, & q4 right ?

Comment: @jon No, only q1 and q2. q1 accepts the empty string, and q2 accepts both `b` and `ab`. The only way to get to state `q3` is to see a single `a`, which is not in the language, so `q3` is not accepting. `q4` is a dead state and is not reached by any strings in the language.

Comment: thank you sir. I think i need a lot of practice on DFA.

Answer (score 0):

i think this DFA is correct for that language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your attached D.F.A is wrong..
your D.F.A  is acceptable only for €,b,bab but it cannot accept ab.
To make your dfa to accept ab also add a new state to q0 which accepts a and whenever newstate gets input as b send it to a final state.
As it is a d.f.a the inputs which are not required for u  send it  to a new state (DEAD STATE)
The d.f.a for your question is here:
[click here to view the d.f.a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQr8E.png)